# Retrieving a YouTube Disco playlist

Tags: youtube, api

YouTube has [this cool thing](http://www.youtube.com/disco) that creates a "smart playlist" from some starting keywords. I would like to programmatically access the playlist. I've found the [YouTube data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html) but it doesn't discuss the "disco" feature.

One of the answers below suggests using

`http://www.youtube.com/disco?action_search=1&query=XXXXXXXXX`

that will return some JSON with the first video to be played, and a `list` property. Unfortunately, the `list` is a 32-character hex string, whereas normal playlist ID's are 16-character hex strings. This means that the standard data API to retrieve the full playlist doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I must say I I never used youtube data API, so I don't know how useful below information will be.

Let me use an example:

I wanted to create Smashing Pumpkins. I typed the artist name and clicked the "Disco!" button. Using [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) I figured out the requested url was:

```
www.youtube.com/disco?action_search=1&query=smashing%20pumpkins
```

Notice, that spaces are replaced with `%20`. As a response i got simple JSON response:

```
{"url": "\/watch?v=bhMz7x1ZaGM\u0026feature=disco\u0026playnext=1\u0026list=MLGxdCwVVULXe5-F4X_zm6wnblRsnXoPJS"}
```

It was a link to the first song of freshly generated Smashing Pumpkins playlist, which address was `list=MLGxdCwVVULXe5-F4X_zm6wnblRsnXoPJS`. All you have to do know is replacing `\u0026` with `&` and you get a valid link.

I assume the rest magic you want to do is available via official youtube data API.
I hope my research will help you.

**EDIT**

Well, it looks like this playlist generated by youtube/disco is not the same type of playlist that users can generate and that is available via API. The list ID is longer than usuall and when you click "More info about playlist" you are redirected to artists profile. Based on this two facts, i guess it's impossible to retrive generated lists via API. Sorry.

Comment: The format of the playlist doesn't seem to be same as the standard 16-character HEX ID's.

Comment: Well, as I said, I'm nor familiar with Youtube API. I just provided you the way to gather a playlist generated by disco feature. You have to handle the rest on your own. If this format thing is a blocker to you, maybe it's not possible at all?

Comment: @Randomblue: As i mentioned in edit part, i think it's impossible to gain the functionality you requested. I even revised the source code, but there's no sign of typical ID of list.

Answer (score 0):

@Randomblue, how exactly do you want to retrieve this playlist?
You can use the 32 char hex in this url to get a page detailing the playlist

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={HEX}
```

or in an embed playlist iframe, like this:

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list={HEX}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```