# How to get "Top tracks for (artist)" URL by YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube-api, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to programmatically get the URL for "Top tracks for (artist)" playlist on YouTube by YouTube API? The only input should be the artist name (for example "ABBA"), and the output should be the address of "Top tracks for ABBA" playlist, i.e.:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFrGuyw1V8s&feature=list_other&playnext=1&list=AL94UKMTqg-9CB-lr-bPA_nrB-AW5RlrYV

Answer (score 0):

@Ognjen:
I have the same issue - is it possible via youtube-api?

**Edit:**
I found this
[Retrieving a YouTube Disco playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819651/retrieving-a-youtube-disco-playlist)

However OP has the same problem, i would consider this as a solution.